# Accessing variable from dict by suppling a variable to a playbook

Tags: ansible

I have the following dict:

```
webpaket:
  "001":
    projekt: "Test"
    domain: "testdomain.de"
    subdomain: "test"
    fqdn: "test.testdomain.de"
    serveradmin: "webmaster@testdomain.de"
    ip: "*"
    ssl: "true"
    password: "somepass"
    vhost: ""
    symfony: "true"
    localdb: "true"
    clusterdb: "false"
    localdb_pgsql: "false"
```

This is the playbook:

```
---
# file: webpaket-remove.yml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    removeweb: "{{ webpaket[webid] }}"
  roles:
    - { role: webpaket-remove, stage: 'dev' }
```

This is the task:

```
---
    - name: Delete Web-Directory for {{ webid }}
      file: path=/test/{{ item.value }} state=absent
      with_dict: "{{removeweb}}"
```

Id like to access a variable from it by giving an argument to ansible playbook like so:

```
ansible-playbook -l testserver.de --check --diff webpaket-remove.yml --extra-vars "webid=001"
```

When i run it i get this output:

```
ok: [testserver.de] => (item={'key': 'projekt', 'value': 'Test'})
ok: [testserver.de] => (item={'key': 'domain', 'value': 'testdomain.de'})
```

How can i access a keys value?

if i use item.value.projekt i get:
`"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'projekt' is undefined`

item[projekt] also doesent work, im out of ideas here :/

Answer (score 1):

*removeweb* isn't a directory. *projekt* shall be addressed directly

```
- file:
    path: "/test/{{ removeweb['projekt'] }}"
    state: absent
```